# Method run on error with MiniTest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

How can I have a method be called on error when using Minitest with Rails, to generate some extra information about the error that just happened?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using something like [pry](https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails) or [debugger](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger) to get more information? I also find liberally sprinkling puts statements throughout the code helpful to ensure that methods I think are being called, are actually called and to show variable values.

Comment: I use a debugger, but when a test crashes, I just want to generate a screenshot of Poltergeist, but only if it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

This was as simple as:

```
def teardown
  if !passed?
    call_method_for_failure
  end
end
```